# Nginx: listen to 8080 for proxy_pass, but not 80

Tags: django, nginx

I can't seem to make this nginx config work on port 80. I tried to deploy a django application using nginx and gunicorn. I used the following command to run gunicorn:

```
gunicorn myproj.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8001 --workers=9
```

The following is the nginx config file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproj`:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
    location /static/ {
       root /webapps/myproj/;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except that I have to enter `http://localhost:8080/` locally or `http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/` for the application to run correctly. Without the port number 8080, the page would not be found.

However, if I change the `listen 8080;` into `listen 80;` in the config file (`myproj`) and enter `http://localhost/` locally or `http://xxx.xxx.xxx/` remotely, the page only shows the welcome message from nginx. Nginx seems not forwarding the request to my application. What was the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify domain or IP to bind to.

```
listen XXX.XXX.XXX:80;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because other server with `listen 80;` exists.

You can remove other server defenition. Or change `listen 80;` to `listen 80 default_server;`. Or use `server_name` directive for name-based process.

Read this about how nginx decides which server should process the request: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html